# Salvaging a "broken" hard drive

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, readonly

My girlfriend's macbook's hard drive failed, so I gave her a new one and reinstalled OSX on it. Works fine. However, I wanted to see if I could use her old hard drive for backups/fun.

I was able to wipe the partitions on the drive and make one single `ext4` partition on it. I was then able to mount it and check it's size (~230G, perfect).

Then I tried backing up my home directory to the hardrive using `sudo cp -r ~/* /media/tmp` where `/media/tmp` is the mounted filesystem. My home directory is around 35G in size. I was able to get far into the copy, then I received this:

```
sudo cp -r ./* /media/tmp/
root's password:
cp: writing `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/In the Airplane Over the Sea/09 Ghost.mp3': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/In the Airplane Over the Sea/07 Communist Daughter.mp3': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create regular file `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/In the Airplane Over the Sea/06 Holland, 1945.mp3': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/Everything Is': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/1996 - On Avery Island': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/Beauty': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/1998 - In the Aeroplane Over the Sea': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Neutral Milk Hotel/Invent Yourself A Shortcake': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Tim Minchin And The Heritage Orchestra': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Dethklok': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/The Tossers - Discography [77era]': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Porcupine Tree (All Studio Albums)': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Protest The Hero': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/music/Dream Theater': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/pictures': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/media/videos': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/misc': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/Monster Complete Series (Eng.-Dub)': Read-only file system
cp: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/repo': Read-only file system
c    p: cannot create directory `/media/tmp/web': Read-only file system

Message from syslogd@linux-vwzy at Dec 11 21:48:16 ...
 kernel:[950354.789962] journal commit I/O error
```

Pardon me for the personal files there, now you know what kind of music I listen to.

I'm not quite sure exactly what's happening here. Are there bad sectors on the hard drive? What does the `kernel:[950354.789962] journal commit I/O error` message mean?

Whatever the issue, is there a way I can fix this? What if I determine where the issue lies on the disk and never write up that sector, would that work?

**Update** So supposedly the os ran into too many errors while writing to the disk, and put it into read-only mode as a response. *So I guess my only question is if there is a way around this? Is this problem directly related to the size of data I write on the disk (ie if I only write 1G will the data be safe as long as I don't touch those bad parts)?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unmount the drive and run `badblocks -n` on it. This will rewrite every sector on the drive — read-then-write, so it's nondestructive — which forces the drive to swap in a fresh sector for every dodgy one found during the pass.

If `badblocks` can't fix it, you could step up to [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) which does that and more.

If either of those "fixes" the drive but you get more data errors later, you have a continual degradation going on, and no fix will be permanent.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply on this. I ran `badblocks -n on the device a couple times, and each time it found SEVERAL "bad" blocks and would lock my computer up. I've given up on this hard drive unless there are any other options. I will accept this answer seeing as it actually showed me what was wrong with my drive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is run a SMART check.

smartctl -t long /dev/whatever

which will tell you it's running a long smart test and roughly how long it will take.

Then run
smartctl -l /dev/whatever
It will tell you how much of the test has been completed and what errors have been seen. Also if the drive is unusable it will tell you.

Comment: You need to give some option to `-l` btw. See `smartctl -h` for the available options